# Generate a Unique ID for an entity

Tags: java, lagom

I'm working on Lagom project and one of the requirement is to uniquely identify each user's document.

A document has an id that I should generate each time a user adds a document.

My idea is simple to guarantee the unicity of the ID:

- generate a random string ID (NOT UUID)
- query the database for the generated ID
- IF query returns 0 hits THEN the ID is unique and I should return it to the caller
- IF query returns 1 hit THEN repeat all steps.

I've implemented the `DocumentEventProcessor extends ReadSideProcessor<DocumentEvent>` and `DocumentRepository`
to be able to query the database.

My problem is how to write the function that iteratively (recursively maybe) query the database until new random ID returns.

Comment: Why not use a UUID? It is invented for exactly that.

Comment: business rule : the ID should be a 7 caracters String

Comment: Then use a sequence (or a similar concept) in the DB. No need to do several tries.

Comment: The system is distributed. Using a sequence either make no sense, or is hard to manage.

Comment: But then your solution has exactly the same problem as it relies on a central database.

Comment: why does the ID  have to be random?

Comment: @Henry is right, what you're proposing to implement is pretty similar to what database sequence numbers implement for you, with the exception that as your data grows, finding an unused id by just randomly generating ids is going to become much more expensive. Don't try and invent your own id generation mechanism, trust those who are smarter than all of us, if you're not willing to use a stateless generator like random UUIDs, use a database to generate it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you may use the following approach:

assumptions:
- distributed system,
- 7 characters long ID,
- you can assign each node a unique value - hostId (maybe last digits from your host IP?)

what to do:
- have a per node Singleton which will generate the ID,
- calculate uniqueNumericID by concatenating the hostId and the current time in millis (you should store last used timestamp, in case you need more than one ID per millisecond, just add one to the last value until last timestamp >= current timestamp).
- convert this numeric value (decimal) to the number with base say 62 (use characters '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' and recurrently calculate modulo of the (rest of the) value, use the modulo as index of the character).

There should be more than enough space in your 7 characters long ID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how does this guarantees the uniqueness between different nodes, 
I know that the possibility of a collision is very minuscule but if it happens it can break the APP

Comment: one of the assumptions was that you can arbitrary assign a unique value for each node, e.g. by deriving it from host's IP.

Comment: Example: take the last byte from the IP, you will have values between 0-255, you would need to assure this string has always 3 digits (you can for example allways add 100), so that it starts from 100 and ends with 355 (lets take 123 as example). You then append the timestamp to this value as string (say your timestamp is 22222222), you than get: 12322222222 as your ID. Convert it to long and then to base 62 as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a while loop?

```
SaveDocumentWithNewId(){
//what pseudocode. 
String newRandomId = null;
while(result.size() != 0 )
newRandomId = GenerateRandomID();
ArrayList result= queryToDatabase(newRandomId);
}

document.setId(newRandomId );
}
```

Comment: That's another varient of my solution. I had a problem implementing that in lagom. It uses lambdas to handle the result. Cannot use simple loop.

Comment: The idea to use a while loop can be ok, but your suggestion is rather bad. You're querying the database with the generated id and then check if the list is empty ... thus if it isn't empty, then you'll fetch an object from the database without needing it. That costs time and resources.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, that is true I would need to think a bit harder :)

Comment: You can let the database perform the check and let it return a boolean value. This would avoid fetching an unneeded object from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the read side (i.e. your database) to guarantee the uniqueness of ids. In Lagom (and any CQRS based system, for that matter), the read side will always be only eventually consistent. So you could end up in a situation where two nodes generate the same id and the database will tell both that it doesn't exist, because it hasn't caught up yet.

What you need to do instead is make sure you can distinguish between a newly created, unused `PersistentEntity`, and one that already has a document associated with it. Then you use the `PersistentEntityRegistry` to get the `PersistentEntity` for your newly generated key. If the entity already existed, generate a new key. If not, you have your key.

The algorithm - generate new IDs until you found an unused one - remains the same, just make sure you use the `PersistentEntityRegistry` to check for uniqueness, not the read side.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **costly process** to check whether an ID generated is unique by searching the database. I will suggest you create your own **UUID(Like a GUID)** which should be **unique across systems** and which is also based on the requirement(i.e 7 characters long).

You may create your own ID by taking the inetAddress of the system and attaching a random number to it and then generating a message digest out of it and then according to your requirement you can trim out 7 characters from it.

By doing so you will have unique ids across the system as well as fulfill your requirement.

For reference [click here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56)